# Do ad impressions count when you are on your test device for android?

Tags: android, admob

So I am looking into my adMob account, and I see the number of impressions for ads. I have a test device that is listed as a test device in the apk.  My question is does my test device ads count as impressions in adMob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, test advertisements count nothing. They are just test Ads just to test or preview our app with advertisements. They do count surely if are not test Ads. Hope you got your answer!

Comment: Mention not! I love to help people :-)